# GitHub hook not working over SSL

Tags: git, ssl, github, githooks, cloudflare

I've got a GitHub hook setup to send repository push updates to my web server so it can pull code automatically.

Since upgrading my website to support SSL and adding a rule to force all requests to use https, the hook has stopped working. I thought the fix would be as simple as prefixing `https://` to my website hook URL on github, but this hasn't worked.

This is the only output GitHub provides:

[image]

As you can see, everything was working fine last night.

I've tried [verifying my SSL certificate chain and it seems fine](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://unisaver.co.uk). I've also tried mimicking the request GitHub sends using POSTMAN without any problems.

I have a funny feeling CloudFlare may be the root cause of this problem, however turning it off isn't an option at the moment. How else can I try debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, as a workaround, you might want to [recreate your webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook), this time adding:

**`insecure_ssl`**: An optional string that determines whether the SSL certificate of the host for url will be verified when delivering payloads.

Set it to `"1"` (verification is not performed), and see if your webhook successfully contact your server through its https url.